# The usage of liquibase-maven-plugin with testcontainers

Tags: java, postgresql, liquibase, testcontainers

Suppose I have this plugin configuration (with hsqldb):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>build</id>
            <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>update</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <changeLogFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/liquibase/db.changelog-master.xml
                </changeLogFile>
                <driver>org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver</driver>
                <url>jdbc:hsqldb:file:${project.build.directory}/hsqldb/sample;shutdown=true</url>
                <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
                <logging>off</logging>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

I want to change hsqldb to postgres. I suppose that it's possible to use `testcontainers` here. But I'm not able to correctly set it up.

If it's possible, could anyone help with the sample configuration? Or maybe there are other solutions?

To note: I currently use this db in another plugin (`schemacrawler`) alongside, so there is no java code used and it's not related to the unit tests.

Comment: Take a look at https://the-codeslinger.com/2020/04/26/integration-testing-with-docker-maven-plugin-postgresql-flyway/ - it uses Flyway, but you should be able to use Liquibase and SchemaCrawler

Comment: @SualehFatehi thanks! I've already implemented it with groovy plugin + testcontainers but the same should definitely work `docker-maven-plugin` too. I'm gonna experiment with this plugin in my spare time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Testcontainers via a small `groovy-maven-plugin` snippet, for example, the following would start a Postgres container:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
  <artifactId>groovy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <!-- Start the container in any phase before the actual code
           generation is required, i.e. at the latest in
           generate-sources -->
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>execute</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <source>
          db = new org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer(
                  "postgres:latest")
            .withUsername("${db.username}")
            .withDatabaseName("postgres")
            .withPassword("${db.password}");
             
          db.start();
 
          // After you've started the container, collect its generated
          // JDBC URL (which contains a random port)
          project.properties.setProperty('db.url', db.getJdbcUrl());
        </source>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
   
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

This example lacks graceful shutdown. It is also taken from the jOOQ article about how one can use Testcontainers to generate Java classes from the database schema: https://blog.jooq.org/using-testcontainers-to-generate-jooq-code

Comment: Thanks, got it working. Also, the good thing about testcontainers is that the created container will be deleted automatically by ryuk so you don't need to perform additional actions in this case